# Order Django queryset by value closest to 0

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-queryset

I have a queryset that is returning a list of entries that are tied for the lead in a contest...

```py
    leaders = ContestEntry.objects.filter(name=game, wins=wins)
```

After I get this data I need to put them in order by a second field ('difference') as a tie breaker. The problem I can't figure out is I need the order to be by the number closest to 0. There will be a lot of negative and positive numbers.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29305681/8889736) answer the following code should give you the right results.

```
from django.db.models import Func, F

leaders = ContestEntry.objects.filter(name=game, wins=wins).annotate(abs_diff=Func(F('difference'), function='ABS')).order_by('abs_diff').first()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The only think I had to edit out was the '- difference' before function='ABS' ... Wouldnt work otherwise. Thanks so much for taking the time out

Answer (score 2):

You can use Django's [**`Abs`** function <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/database-functions/#abs):

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.functions import Abs

ContestEntry.objects.filter(name=game, wins=wins).order_by(
    abs_diff=Abs(F('difference') - difference).asc()
).first()
```